# is it ok to say "if you bend / duck your head all the way down onto the floor right after meal like that, you may throw up"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> ​[duck](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/duck_2) [intransitive, transitive] to move your head or body downwards to
>   avoid being hit or seen
>
> He had to duck as he came through the door.
>
> duck (down) (behind/under something) We ducked down behind the wall
>   so they wouldn't see us.
>
> He ducked under the overhanging branches.
>
> He just managed to duck out of sight.
>
> duck something She ducked her head and got into the car.
>
> She ducked under the railings and ran towards him.

---

> [bend](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bend) 1 [intransitive, transitive] to move part of your body so that it
>   is not straight or so that you are not upright
>
> Lee bent and kissed her.
>
> She bent her head.
>
> Bend your knees, but keep your back straight.
>
> bend over
>
> Emma bent over to pick up the coins.
>
> bend down
>
> I bent down to lift the box off the floor.
>
> bend towards/across etc
>
> He bent towards me and whispered in my ear.

---

My child often "**bends or ducks her head all the way down onto the floor right after meal**", which may make her throw up.

She could stand and bend her head all the way down like this

[image]

or, She could sit and put her head down on the floor like this

[image]

or She could stand and bend her head with her hands on the floor like this

[image]

Could I say generally for all similar situations like this

"**If you bend / duck your head all the way down onto the floor right after meal like that, you may throw up**"?

Comment: "Duck" implies staying the right way up but bending the knees or the neck so as to avoid a blow or to hide behind something. What you are talking about is putting the head lower than the body, which is not quite the same.

Comment: @KateBunting, is it ok to say "don't bend your head all the way down like that"?

Comment: Yes - or I might describe 1 and 3 as 'turning upside down'.

Comment: @KateBunting, what about "bend your head upside down like that"? is it idiomatic? (the girl in the site bends her head upside down to dry her hair https://www.musely.com/tips/How-To-Grow-12-Inches-Of-Hair-In-A-Week/30520650)

Comment: I would probably advise a child not to 'turn upside down' after a meal, but you could say 'bend' or 'hang your head upside down'.